# How to disable copy paste in form.io textfield

Tags: javascript, formbuilder, form.io

Adding Confirm Password field but want to disable the onpaste event in Confirm Password and oncopy event in Password field.

Tried using custom validation, calculated value but they are getting triggered after the value is submitted, have little to no knowledge of how to use Logic actions for this scenario.

Comment: Have a look at the following
: https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/2432.

Comment: Have you tried using the [past event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) for the paste part?

Comment: Hey. Please also share the code or snippet of it here for better understanding. Regards!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.